# IntelliJ IDEA, SBT - IDE generates junk modules conflicting with mpeltonen sbt-idea plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for development in Scala with SBT.
I have **IntelliJ IDEA's SBT** plugin in combination with **mpeltonen sbt-idea** plugin.

After running `gen-idea` command in SBT console it generates IDEA-related files for two modules (based on my project name). But whenever I edit *`build.sbt`* file, IDEA itself also tries to generate two modules with the name `trunk` (as I have my project in folder named "trunk").

As a result I'm having two pairs of modules (every time I allow refresh in IDEA). See picture.
[image: SBT-IDEA]

After that IDEA underlines many pieces of code with red lines (like errors). To get rid of them I should delete `trunk`-modules manually.

Can I configure smth in IDEA or mpeltonen plugin to have just one pair of modules? Preferred is mpeltonen version (though it tries to add "scala compiler" as compiler whilst I need "scala compiler bundle").

**UPD**. IntelliJ IDEA ver is 13.1.3  (build #IC-135.909), SBT IntelliJ plugin 1.6.1, mpeltonen sbt-idea ver 1.6.0

Comment: Are your modules shown at Settings->SBT->Linked SBT Projects? If yes, try to remove them from there.

Comment: Yep, there is linked project under "Project Settings" with name "trunk". I don't know how it got there... And I don't see context menu options to delete it..

Comment: Maybe the problem can be solved by: - Not Enable auto-import checkbox when opening/importing the .sbt file; or not opening the .sbt file to import the project but the generated project file.

Comment: I do not have autoimport enabled..

Comment: Hello Alec, did you solve the problem since then?

Comment: Not yet... Just manually removing trunk-projects each time... To get it working